# How to make a single function return Array of provided Array and value?

Tags: java, arrays

I am working on a project where I need to push elements into Array. I made a function as follow to push value inside array:

```
    public float[] insertFloatIntoArray(float[] arr, float val) {
        float newarr[] = new float[arr.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        newarr[arr.length] = val;
        return newarr;
    }
```

But is there any way to make it generic so that if I provide an Array of any data type with value of same datatype and return new array of same datatype. doing so can make me avoid replica of code and function for various data types.

Comment: Yes using Java generics.

Comment: Only with object classes, not primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to return an array because arrays are based on pointers ,and whenever you change an array in a method , it will also affect to the array in main or in the location that you sent.

```
 public void insertFloatIntoArray(float[] arr, float val) {
    float newarr[] = new float[arr.length + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        newarr[i] = arr[i];
    }
    newarr[arr.length] = val;
    
}
```

This is the functionality that you desire.

Lastly , If you have two arrays.You can send both as parameters ,so it will be way easier than what you try.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something loke this:

```
public <T extends Number> T[] insertFloatIntoArray(Class<T> clazz, T[] arr, T val) {
        T newarr[] = (T[]) Array.newInstance(clazz, arr.length + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            newarr[i] = arr[i];
        }
        newarr[arr.length] = val;
        return newarr;
    }
```

but in this case you must use object wrap of numper types (`Float` instead `float`, `Integer` instead `int` etc)

```
insertFloatIntoArray(Integer.class, <old array>, <int or Integer value>);
insertFloatIntoArray(Float.class, <old array>, <float or Float value>);
```

array content class you can get by this code:

```
Class componentType = arr.getClass().getComponentType();
```

After all I think you should use `ArrayList` for this

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to say that this is a good idea...  And you lose type safety so may well run into lots of errors when calling it...   But this can be done for primitives and non-primitives alike using the `Array` class:

```java
public static <T> T insertAtEnd(final T array, final Object toAppend) {
    // Find the type of the provided array
    final Class<?> klass = array.getClass().getComponentType();
    final int arrayLength = Array.getLength(array);

    // Create a new array with the provided type, but with one more length.
    final Object newArray = Array.newInstance(klass, arrayLength + 1);

    // Copy the old array's contents into the first elements of the new array.
    System.arraycopy(array, 0, newArray, 0, arrayLength);

    // Set the final element of the array to the given value.
    Array.set(newArray, arrayLength, toAppend);

    return (T) newArray;
}
```

(Note the generic is only used to avoid the caller having to cast the array back at the end...  If you replace `T` with `Object` this works completely without generics as well.)

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) if you need to add new elements to it. Then you can just call the add method on it. If you need atomic types like int, float, etc... Use the [wrapper classes](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_wrapper_classes.asp) Integer, Float for them.